# Display subtitles only on a black video background

Tags: ffmpeg, subtitles

I am trying to use `ffmpeg` to achieve the following:
I have a live (.ts) file being streamed in from a satellite broadcast. This stream is sent unmolested to a projector for display. I take this same stream and divert it to a small monitor where I wish to only display the subtitles, (on a black background). I believe the following would work, using a combination of ffmpeg and ffplay, but I cannot get the syntax right. I will describe the process in words!

Remove the audio stream. Blank or colourise to black the video stream. Retaining the video stream I believe is necessary as the bit mapped subtitles need to map their bits onto something that is synchronized with the original! Output this stream using ffplay.
If someone could tell me whether this is achievable, and if so how it might be fashioned using said facilities, I would be very appreciative.

Comment: Maybe you can just use a filter to draw a black box over the whole video?

Answer (score 1):

FFMPEG comes with a number of generators including one that creates colour. You can use it as a video source to create your black video. Then map it as your video source and the input subtitle stream from the input.TS to the subtitles, and specify no audio to remove the audio.

```
ffmpeg -i input.ts -f lavfi -i color=color=black -map 1:v -map 0:s -an output.ts
```

should work. I don't have a TS with subtitles on hand to test it. I'm assuming you're playing back the subtitles on a player that generates them from the subtitle stream, rather than burning them in?

More discussion about the syntax here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11640458/how-can-i-generate-a-video-file-directly-from-an-ffmpeg-filter-with-no-actual-in

Comment: May want to add `-c:v copy` to copy over the bitstream.

Comment: Does rawvideo work in an MPEG TS?

Comment: Ah, no, it doesn't. Had forgotten that aspect of the question.